# Effect of updating an app on Google Play on downloads

Tags: android, google-play

There might be a perfectly natural market answer to my question but I'll ask anyway.

I created a game and published it on Google Play in January 2012. After that it has seen a steady increase of downloads (over 50k combined, currently 200-300 a day) and I've kept updating it a lot. About two or three weeks ago I issued an update that had a weird effect on my new downloads. They almost completely stopped. I'm having a hard time believing that an update similar to what I've issued in the past has this kind of effect on user download decisions. Downloads dropped suddenly from 200-300 a day to 1-10 a day after the update.

I know I don't understand the Google Play search routines and stuff like that very well, but I still would like to know if there's a simple answer to my problem. What are the possibilities that an app upgrade will affect the visibility of the software.

BTW: My game update did not change the SDK requirements or available devices.

EDIT: I noticed a new permission has appeared in my application: "test access to protected storage" after I changed SDK target to 17. Can this affect my downloads?

Comment: Since most of the downloads comes by organic search. You should keep a tap on search keyword ranking for your app. If google pushes your apps keyword rank higher then you will see sharp increase in download & vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try and attempt an answer.

As per my understanding, *Updates* do not count in the number of *Downloads*. Simply because, the user has already downloaded them once. The Download count represents the unique number of downloads.

Unless the Update broke something or changed something drastic enough to drive away potential down-loaders, it has no effect on the number of downloads (per day) going down or going up. It may also be due to negative feed back and / or comments for your app. And although I cannot claim or give a source, I am almost certain the Update/s has nothing to do with stats going down.

Hoping any of this will help.

**UPDATE**

It is quite possible that the new permission is responsible. That being said, it really is a very subjective decision for the user to decide on the installation (because of the permission). Perhaps, to possibly remedy the situation, assuming the reason is the permission, you could put up a list of permissions used by the app and state the reason for using them in your app's listing. But that is the best that can be done to mitigate a further loss of users. Plus, you may perhaps see the stats getting back to normal too. Good luck. ;-)

Comment: I noticed my app requests a new permission after I changed the target to Jelly bean. Updated my question.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it is the most informative answer. I am fairly sure the permission and some other design decisions have negatively impacted my downloads.

Answer (score 3):

From the day the app was launched till 30 days after that, your app appears in the 'Top New Free/Paid' app section in the play store (appears at almost the top in your app category). So for the first 30 days, downloads are awesome. Playstore suddenly drops it from the 'Top New Free/Paid' section and now your app will only appear in 'Top Free/Paid' section which is much more crowded and has more established apps to fight for a place.

The update surely has to affect on the downloads.

I will go so far and say that even the change in permission requirement is not responsible for the drop. One more permission request might change the mind of 10% of your potential consumers but not more than that.

Comment: 'Top New Free/Paid' app section in the play store nowadays does not appear

Comment: Don't think getting a position in Top new free section gets app a lot of downloads. I mean when was the last time you downloaded an app from there ?

Comment: @VihaanVerma Used to work 3 years back when i last updated my app. Can't say for today.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I changed the default language to English in the Play developer console - Control panel, the number of downloads drops from 300-400 to 1-30, it was frustrating. Before when I looked for my app by its own name it would come in the first or second option, after changing the default language dropped to the 30 position, then I thought if I switch back to the old default language maybe return to the first position, but this was more Terrible because the last change caused it to disappear from the positions. It only appeared with complicated searches that included keywords placed in the description of my app.

My app always supported 2 languages Spanish and English, by mistake when I first uploaded the app, I placed the default version in Spanish.

Comment: This is more a story about a similar experience than an answer. It doesn't give an answer or a better explanation of the problem. I guess your intention was to keep the discussion up for this problem but the answer functionality is not the best way to do so. Rather vote up the original question to give it more attention.

Answer (score 1):

Typically there is no effect if you do not change the manifest sdk, feature or permission requirements.
It could be that what you see is not related to the version, but rather something else. Most likely it is because 30 days passed since launch. On the first 30 days after a new app is published, you get some boost from Google, but after 30 days, it stops.